# Is an object an autorelease when it's set equal to another

Tags: objective-c, object, memory, memory-management, autorelease

I have a question regarding memory management in Objective C.

Here is the code...

```
SomeObject * objectA;
SomeObject * objectB;

objectA = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

objectB = objectA;
```

From a memory perspective, is object B an autorelease object?  Is it weak/strong? Is it simply pointing to object A and will become nil if object A is released?

Comment: objectB is not an object. it is a reference

Comment: So if ObjectA is released then objectB is nil?

Comment: i'm not sure if you're talking about ARC or not?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the logic.  Let's assume I'm in control of releasing the object and I release objectA after making objectB = objectA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `objectA` and `objectB` will have a strong reference, so if they're both pointing to the same object, then it won't be deallocated until either both of them are set to `nil` or they both go out of scope. This is of course assuming ARC is enabled. If ARC isn't enabled, then your object will only be deallocated if you call `release` on it.

Now, under ARC, if you wanted only one of them to have a strong reference to the object, then you could put the `__weak` qualifier in front of one of the variables. Of course in your example, if you make `objectA` weak, then it will result in your object being deallocated immediately, so both of your pointers will remain `nil`.

Comment: Ok, so the reference count would go to 2 when objectB = objectA?

Comment: @user1539603 You shouldn't generally care what the reference count is, but yes, it should be incrementing it when you do that. Keep in mind that Apple's documentation for the `retainCount` method says not to use it, and that it's of no value in debugging memory management issues for multiple reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I understand ARC manages this, I just wanted to fully understand the methodology.

Comment: @user1539603 Well I hope my answer helped. :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that ARC is enabled, and objectA and objectB are local variables, then they both act as strong pointers. So setting objectA to nil has no effect on objectB or the underlying object. Setting objectA and objectB to nil will release the underlying object. Also when objectA and objectB go out of scope, the underlying object will be released.

This code

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog( @"dealloc underlying object" );
}
@end

- (void)test
{
    SomeClass *objectA;
    SomeClass *objectB;

    objectA = [[SomeClass alloc]init];
    objectB = objectA;
    NSLog( @"objectA=%p objectB=%p", objectA, objectB );

    objectA = nil;
    NSLog( @"objectA=%p objectB=%p", objectA, objectB );

    NSLog( @"end of test method" );
}
```

produces this output

```
objectA=0x7a4d800 objectB=0x7a4d800
objectA=0x0 objectB=0x7a4d800
end of test method
dealloc underlying object
```

Comment: "Setting either one to nil will release it."  That statement is patently false, and shows a profound lack of understanding of the concept of reference counting. "After all strong references are gone, it will be deallocated."  That statement is technically true, but is off-topic given the code snippet in the OP's question.

Comment: I think it is you who has a profound lack of understanding. Setting a `__strong` object pointer in ARC will release the previous value and retain the new value.